# Peer dependency errors from npm even though actual dependency version correctly follows semver

Tags: npm, dependency-management

I'm getting `npm ERR! invalid` errors when I try `npm ls` or `npm install`, and it seems like npm is incorrectly thinking peers have incompatible versions. A good example (I get several of these at a time):

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /MYLOCALPROJECTDIRECTORY/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle requires image-type@'^0.1.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /MYLOCALPROJECTDIRECTORY/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/image-type,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.1.4
```

According to the rules of semver, the caret "^" operator should match a requirement of `^0.1.1` with an actual dependency of version `0.1.4` just fine.

I've installed Node v0.10.30 with npm v1.4.23 using Homebrew (both the latest stables), running OS X Mountain Lion. I'd appreciate tips on finding how to reliably reproduce this - last time I totally uninstalled/reinstalled Node and npm, same local npm modules and everything, and could not find the error again. Came back to work the next day, tried to install some grunt plugin, and ran into all these errors again.

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to reproduce it, I bet you can solve it by removing the node_modules folder, cleaning the cache and reinstalling:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

I know this is not an actual answer, but I guess it's better than uninstalling/reinstalling  node/npm.